# Pagination with Rails 5 - Having two models on "newsfeed" and paginating the total?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I am building a web app that has a "newsfeed" with two models (called Event and Suggestion). Is it possible to paginate the newsfeed such that the pagination applies to the total and not either individually? Here is what I have so far in my controller. I tried simply adding the two, though that doesn't work because the result is an array, not an ActiveRecord Association. Thanks in advance!

```
def index
  @ideas = Suggestion.paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 25).order('created_at DESC')
  @ideas += Event.paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 25).order('created_at DESC')

  render :index
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use 'will_paginate', try this. Put this in your initializers:

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

then you can do things like this:

```
@objects = (Suggestion.all + Event.all).sort_by &:created_at
@objects.paginate(:page =>params[:page], per_page: 25)
```

The problem here is performance. This way you will get all records from the database every time, and then perform pagination

Comment: Yes that makes sense there would be a performance issue. Is there a way around this? Because that was my main reason for paginating...

Comment: You could make some kind of a cache. For example a "news" table with fields like :news_type, :news_id, :created_at.  Then use after_create callback on suggestions and events to put data in this table.  Finally, you paginate on this model using joins to fetch data from the actual tables

Comment: news_type is either "suggestion" or "event" and news_id is a reference to entries in those tables